# Parsing JSON with Python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, django

i read about 10 to 12 answer but nothing help me.

i wanna print the url shows in picute  [click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkE0Z.png)  
this is my code :

```
> from urllib.request import urlopen 
> import json as simplejson

> link = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=2290710571.098b867.5cf99a24896b476982c70c47eb0a0413"

> response = urlopen(link)
> data = simplejson.load(response) 
> print (data['data']['0']['image']['standard_resolution']['url'])
```

but i get this error :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

edit1:

> i saw someone say put [0] in you code.
>   if i change
>
> ```
> print (data['data']['0']['image']['standard_resolution']['url'])
> ```
>
> to this
>
> ```
> print (data[0]['data']['0']['image']['standard_resolution']['url'])
>  i will get new error -> KeyError: 0
> ```

edit2:

> and if i change
>
> ```
> data = simplejson.load(response)
> ```
>
> to this
>
> ```
> pdata = simplejson.loads(response)
> ```
>
> i will get new error ->
>
> aise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
>   TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not
>   HTTPResponse

Comment: try `simplejson.loads(response)`

Comment: there is simplejson.loads(response) in code...

Comment: shet... i see now :D . now ill get new error

Comment: raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not HTTPResponse

Comment: @Amin please don't answer in comments. Your advice is incorrect, but a comment can't be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice is to use an integer, not to add an extra two lookups.

```
print(data['data'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'])
```

Note, that data has `images` not `image`.

(Also, there's no reason to import the json library as simplejson. simplejson was a library that was popular before json was included in the standard library; but that was added in version **2.6** and we're on 3.7 now. Just import json and use it.)

Comment: after putting your code ill get new error: aise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not HTTPResponse

Comment: Because you followed Amin's incorrect advice to use `loads`. Don't.